# Evaluating variable - output json file contents

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In the bash shell, I'm trying to read the json file and load to a variable

```
eri@xyz:~/Documents/inbound>e1=$(eval echo $(cat ./deploy/request.json))
```

Upon fetching the output of that variable, I'm seeing `-bash - command not found` along with the actual contents of the .json file

```
eri@xyz:~/Documents/inbound>"$e1"

-bash: { type:Pipeline, category:Software, risk:4, short_description:sample short description text, description:sample detailed description text, assignment_group: Services - Retail Services, cmdb_ci:Retail Service, u_version:1.0, start_date:2017-01-04 18:00:00, end_date:2017-01-04 19:00:00, backout_plan:see department for standard backout plan, implementation_plan:sample implementation plan, test_plan:sample text plan, production_system:false }: command not found
```

Is there a way to suppress the `-bash - command not found` in the output?.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51777888/edit) to include more information.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `eval` - just `e1=$(< ./deploy/request.json)` should do the trick.  (Thanks to @shellter for the syntax — [you don't even need to use `cat`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst#specialities)!)

To show the variable, you want

```
echo "$e1"
```

instead of just `"$e1"`.  `"$e1"` by itself on the command line does not print out the value of `$e1`, unlike many programming-language REPLs.  Instead, it tells bash to try to interpret the entire contents of `$e1` as the name of a command.  It isn't the name of a command, so bash tells you a command by that name cannot be found.

Comment: and you can skip the unneeded `cat` process by using `el=$(< file)` . Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Thanks!  I was wondering if this were a uuoc, but didn't know that syntax.

Comment: its the same idea as `anyProg < file`, but somehow the `$( cmd_substitution)` knows how to do it. Note that  just doing `< file` on the cmd line doesn't produce any output (in my one test just now ;-) ). Glad to share what I know. Good luck to all!